# hide parameter present in the url, without reload the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Actually I think my problem goes beyond the head of the question. I have to include the following link in some hyperlink on my page.

this link will open a login form on the same page (this form is from a government company, I did not develop it and it is the only way to authenticate myself).

```
<a href="https://xxxxxxxx.gov.co/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/SignIn.aspx?ReturnUrl=http://localhost:8010/fiapp/#!/home">autenticate</a>
```

`ReturnUrl`= my page actual

this is the path of my view:

```
http://localhost:8010/fiapp/#!/home"
```

When I finish authenticating successfully, it redirects me to my page. (see the parameter `ReturnUrl`)

When I authenticate, it redirects me to my previous page with the difference that in the url of the browser I get a code called: 'SessionID'

```
http://localhost:8010/fiapp/?_=1&SessionID=xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxx#!/home
```

What I intend is that when I redirect to my website, do not show this information in the url, for security issues, I would like to know what I can do to save this code in some way without the user seeing it.

If someone can give me ideas to rethink the name of the question, your comments are welcome. Thank you very much, I tried to make myself understood.

Comment: You can use cookie ?

Comment: @RITESHARORA for what? Excuse my ignorance

Comment: Sorry for late response. What i  understand you want to remove sessionid from url for security reason.I was thinking a js code that  check if there is session id , then remove it, save cookie and change url to itself again , Page should not reload i think because its a SPA

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 introduced the history.pushState() and history.replaceState() methods, which allow you to add and modify history entries, respectively.

If your link is https://website.com/foo.html
Then, this will cause the URL bar to display https://website.com/bar.html, but won't cause the browser to load bar.html or even check that bar.html exists.

`var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "A title for the page", "bar.html");`

Another example for your case:

`history.pushState("fiapp", "Title", "/fiapp/#!/home");`

Comment: I have tried many things, even that, but it does not work. or in other cases the page is reloaded

Comment: Please look at the url of my project, I do not know if something is wrong.

Comment: try to change the url, but then change it to the page response